# Initialize multiple swipers.js on a single page by using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

First of all, the answers I found on this forum didn't solve my problem.

I'm using `Swiper 8.0.7`.

When I use classes below, only the one with class `"slider-main__body"` gets intitialized. If use a common class `"swiper"` they both include, the both swipers are initialized, however when I use controls (arrows and pagination) on the second slider, the images of the first one are moving. I found a few helpful suggestions, but none of them worked. I will appreciate your help.

```
function initSliders() {
    if (document.querySelector('.slider-main__body')) { 
        new Swiper('.slider-main__body', { 
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 32,
            autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,
            loop: true,
            loopAdditionalSlides: 5,
            preloadImages: false,
            parallax: true,

            pagination: {
                el: '.controls-slider-main__dotts.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },
            
            navigation: {
                prevEl: '.swiper-arrow.swiper-arrow-prev',
                nextEl: '.swiper-arrow.swiper-arrow-next',
            },
        });
    }           
    if (document.querySelector('.slider-rooms__body')) { 
        new Swiper('.slider-rooms__body', { 
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            slidesPerView: auto,
            spaceBetween: 24,
            autoHeight: true,
            speed: 800,
            loop: true,
            loopAdditionalSlides: 5,
            preloadImages: false,
            parallax: true,

            pagination: {
                el: '#swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },

            navigation: {
                prevEl: '#swiper-arrow-prev',
                nextEl: '#swiper-arrow-next',
            },
        });
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        initSliders();
    });
```

Comment: Did you even check the console? It throws error `auto is not defined`. That's why 2nd slider doesn't work. You have `slidesPerView: auto` but it [should be string](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slidesPerView) `slidesPerView: 'auto'`.

Comment: I am still a beginner. Thank you very much!